# ZipException duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter$MyDataSetObserver.class

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter$MyDataSetObserver.class - List item

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.omairm.hoops"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
            main {
                jni.srcDirs = []
            }
        }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'){exclude module: 'Support-v4'}
    compile files('libs/PTAdRevMob.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
}
```

[image]

[image]

Do I need to delete the CursorAdapter.class?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to use JAR files for? You realize you are using really old libraries, right?

Comment: @cricket_007 that's what i get from a buildbox export, I haven't the slightest and I will be learning more as i go along

Comment: I see... I might suggest learning Java basics before diving into Android. Then you can optionally learn more about Maven or Gradle...

Answer (score 1):

You should add something similar to this to your build.gradle, where the duplicate file is added to exclude

```
android {
     configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, suggesting that he adds the duplicated files as shown

Comment: I'm not sure on how to code this with the duplicate file. I'm literally a newbie to the coding world

Answer (score 1):

> do i need to delete the cursoradapter.class

It's good that you are reading the error and recognize a least part of what it's telling you, but you can't just delete a class from a JAR file. The build process that Gradle goes through is only throwing the error at the first class conflict it found, and there would be more if you were to only focus on that one.

---

My suggestion would be to find the correct and current libraries for each of the JAR files you have and remove the jar files as you go.

Also, try to actually use a number value rather than only a plus for the version because you don't want to be using alpha / beta releases of a library that'll change every few weeks

If you [search around Maven](https://mvnrepository.com) you can replace most of those JAR files

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+"
    // Don't use just a plus here 
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}
    compile files('libs/PTAdRevMob.jar')
    compile group: 'com.squareup.dagger', name: 'dagger', version: '1.2.2'
    // compile group: 'com.nineoldandroids', name: 'library', version: '2.4.0'
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that nineoldandroids is deprecated. Since you're using `minSdkVersion 14`, I don't think you even need it.

Dagger has also had many releases since version 1.2 but it already includes javax inject framework (see compiled dependencies https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.dagger/dagger/1.2.2)

You'll definitely want to take a look at [Google Play | Selectively compiling APIs into your executable](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split) too.

Note that if `PTAdRevMob.jar` has any classes that still conflict with any other library here, you'll still get an error, and will probably need to switch to a different Ad provider